# How to list all pages in a folder using Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've got a folder with many markdown files which are pages. I would like to list in my header links to all of them. How can I do this in Jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a collection object and iterate over it.

If the folder with html pages is named `_articles`:

1. define a collection in `_config.yml`, like:

```yaml
collections:
  articles:
    output: true # to make jekyll generate html pages
```

2. iterate over them in any html view, like

```html
{% for article in site.articles %}
  <a href="{{ article.url }}"> link to article </a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more about collections here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/